# How to pass XML document as parameter to wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm writing WCF service. I need to pass XML to service and then to write that XML to database which is not important right now. Something like this:

```
[OperationContract]
void InsertReport(XmlObjectSerializer xmlDoc);
```

Anyone did this?

[EDIT]

I also need to test this, but WCF default client cant do that...

Comment: Maybe you can just use the string location of the xmlDoc and then load it within the method.

Comment: Why not pass it as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve this by generating a sting from the xml. The saved data in the database will always get converted to a string anway.